# Ejabberd mod_muc and mod_muc_room differentiation

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api, ejabberd-saas

Im looking at ejabberd code and realized that there are two modules that left me very confusing.

mod_muc.erl and mod_muc_room.erl. Im not really sure how to differentiate between them. Any inputs or examples as to when each of the modules come to play and what exactly is each one serving. ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mod_muc serves as muc service for ejabberd server per host.All requests related to room service has to go via mod_muc.

mod_muc_room serves purpose of MUC room(as name suggests).It is a kind of room level abstraction.All operations related to room(joining, leaving, messaging) will be handled by this.mod_muc sends request to mod_muc_room